# Adding views dynamically in a for loop results in haphazard positioning - Android

Tags: android

I am adding views dynamically to a relative layout (let's say container) in a for loop. There is some thing strange I am noticing. 
When adding rows one below the other in a relative layout in a for loop, **I see that the first time a few of the views are overlapping. But when I lock and unlock the screen, I can see that the views are placed correctly.**
Should I be aware of something when adding views dynamically to a relative layout?

**Edit**
I have found a solution as to how to get rid of this (please check my answer). But I would be more than glad to accept an answer that analyses this problem and tells me why this happens.
I have simplified to code and the comments should give a good idea as to what I am doing.

```
int prev_id=ID_OF_THE_ELEMENT_ABOVE;

/*Empty RelativeView with width and height as MATCH_PARENT and WRAP_CONTENT respectively*/
RelativeLayout container=(RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);
while(ThereIsData){
                      /*GET THE DATA HERE THAT HAS TO BE ASSIGNED TO EACH TEXTVIEW*/
            ...


                        /* ADD TEXTVIEW #1 below prev_id/
            ...
            ...

                        /*ADD TEXTVIEW #2 (WITH BASELINE OF TEXTVIEW#
            ...
            ...

                        /*TEXTVIEW #3 (BELOW TEXTVIEW#1)*/
            ...
            ...                               

                        /*TEXTVIEW #4 (BELOW TEXTVIEW#2)*/
                        ...
            ...

                        /*ASSIGN THE ID OF TEXTVIEW#3 TO prev_id SO THAT 
                  IN THE NEXT ITERATION TEXTVIEW#1 CAN USE prev_id
                         */
                        prev_id=ID(TEXTVIEW#2);

            /*ADD TEXTVIEWS CREATED IN THIS ITERATION*/
             container.addView(TEXTVIEW#1);
                         container.addView(TEXTVIEW#2);
                         container.addView(TEXTVIEW#3);
                         container.addView(TEXTVIEW#4);                     
  }
```

Comment: Any updates on your problem?

Comment: @KirilAleksandrov : I have solution to the problem. You can checkout my answer. I am trying to find out why this behavior is happening. You have given me a solution but I am more interested in knowing what is happening internally, that is causing the problem.

Answer (score 5):

It is due to the fact that you are having a `RelativeLayout` with `height` as `WRAP_CONTENT`, and adding a view doesn't refresh the whole container at that time.. so as you answered you can add a line to `measure` the dimensions explicitly or `invalidate` the view to recreate it completely.

In any case `LinearLayout` would be better to opt-for as it will automatically arrange the children in `horizontal` or `vertical` manner and you can even add the new view in any place other than last position and it will automatically be updated..

Comment: Can you point to a documentation that says that the view does not refresh on adding child it it? Also then why did it work when I locked and unlocked the screen?

Comment: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.0_r1/android/view/ViewGroup.java#ViewGroup.addView%28android.view.View%2Cint%2Candroid.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams%29 ----- Check this out here measure is not called after adding the child view...
and when you lock/unlock the screen whole view is recreated and this is even true if you open/close keyboard, do some gesture, etc

Comment: What do you mean by the 'view was recreate'? Do you mean redrawn?

Comment: The grep code you provided, calls invalidate(). Which is used for redrawing. If redraw was the problem, then it should have worked right

Comment: Life saving answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I used to struggle against common issues a year ago, when I was working on a library for dynamically creating layouts from XML files (as Android does not support this). So when you dynamically add views to a `RelativeLayout` you have to take in mind a few things:

1. Create the container `View` (in this case the `RelativeLayout`)
2. Create all views without assigning any layout parameters.
3. Add all child views to the container.
4. Iterate over the container's children and populate each child's layout parameters. This is needed because when the relational constraints are applied an `Excpetion` is thrown if the relative `View` is missing (was not previously added to the container).

This is an example code taken from the project I used to work on. Take in mind that it is just a single part so it contains references to classes that are not defined in the Android API. I am sure it will give you the basic idea of dynamically creating `RelativeLayot`:

```
private void setChildren(RelativeLayout layout, T widget,
        InflaterContext inflaterContext, Context context,
        Factory<Widget, View> factory) {
    List<Widget> children = widget.getChildren();
    if (Utils.isEmpty(children))) {
        return;
    }

    // 1. create all children
    for (Widget child : children) {
        View view = factory.create(inflaterContext, context, child);
        layout.addView(view);
    }

    // 2. Set layout parameters. This is done all children are created
    // because there are relations between children.
    for (Widget child : children) {
        try {
            View view = ViewIdManager.getInstance().findViewByName(layout, child.getId());

            if (view != null) {
                populateLayoutParmas(child, view);
            }
        } catch (IndexNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Cannot find a related view for " + child.getId(), e);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not yet found the answer to why this is happening. But I have found a solution. After adding each row in the loop, call `container.measure(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);`
This seems to solve the problem. But I really think that `container.addView()` should also be calling `measure()`.

```
/*ADD TEXTVIEWS CREATED IN THIS ITERATION*/
             container.addView(TEXTVIEW#1);
                         container.addView(TEXTVIEW#2);
                         container.addView(TEXTVIEW#3);
                         container.addView(TEXTVIEW#4);
  //---------------------------------------------------------------------
                  container.measure(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

Comment: I disagree. onMeasure is a resource intensive operation so it is a good thing that you can add a lot of views and then eventually call onMeasure at the end to lay out the UI.

Comment: @DKIT : I tried that - adding all the views and then calling measure. But that didn't work. It worked for only when I called measure on each iteration.

Comment: Have you tried calling requestLayout and invalidate/postInvalidate on the parent view?

Answer (score 0):

```html
   
//Declare globally
 LinearLayout[] layout;
 ImageView[] imageView1;
 ImageView[] imageView2;
 ImageView[] imageView3;

// Initialize your layout. It would be RelativeLayout too. Just reference to it.
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mylinear);
  

        // set listview row size as your demand
  layout = new LinearLayout[200];
  imageView1 = new ImageView[200];
  imageView2 = new ImageView[200];
  imageView3 = new ImageView[200];

  for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
   layout[i] = new LinearLayout(this);
   layout[i].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.book_shelf);
   // layout[i].setLayoutParams(new
   // LinearLayout.LayoutParams(android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
   // 120));
   layout[i].setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
     android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 220));

   imageView1[i] = new ImageView(this);
   imageView2[i] = new ImageView(this);
   imageView3[i] = new ImageView(this);

   imageView1[i].setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, 200,
     0.33f));
   imageView1[i].setPadding(0, 20, 0, 0);

   imageView1[i].setImageResource(R.drawable.bibid_one_bankim);
   imageView2[i].setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, 200,
     0.33f));
   imageView2[i].setPadding(0, 20, 0, 0);
   imageView2[i].setImageResource(R.drawable.bibid_two_bankim);

   imageView3[i].setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, 200,
     0.33f));
   imageView3[i].setImageResource(R.drawable.dena_pawna);
   imageView3[i].setPadding(0, 20, 0, 0);

   layout[i].setId(i);
   layout[i].setClickable(true);
   final int j = i;

   layout[i].addView(imageView1[i]);
   layout[i].addView(imageView2[i]);
   layout[i].addView(imageView3[i]);

   ll.addView(layout[i]);
  }
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try adding your views in vertical Linear Layout.
Following link might help you

http://www.myandroidsolutions.com/2012/06/19/android-layoutinflater-turorial/

Inflate your layout in for loop.

Comment: Because we use LayoutInflater for adding dynamic views and the suggested method is very easy to implement. I also used this method for dynamically adding views.